# Best way to handle User authentication + Push Notifiations in Ionic

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework

[Parse](http://parse.com/)? Auth0? [Firebase](http://firebase.com)? Ionic Platform?

I'm so lost... Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I started with Parse recently and I think it will do the job, I have a small amounts of data to send for a finance control  app. I've never worked with a backend before :S

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "backend in a box" then If you are creating an API meant to be consumed by an Ionic application, JWT is probably what you are looking for. Parse, Auth0 etc *may* help. I have not used them. However, if you are building your own backend it will be dependent on what server side framework you are using. It's safe to say that JWT is a good approach on the client side(angular/ionic), but you will need a serverside authentication and account system such as Passport for Node, Devise for Rails etc.. Either of those will handle basic authentication and account management. You will need a JWT layer as well to produce and manage tokens for the client. You can also create a homebrew system if you choose to but the frameworks I mentioned make things quite a bit easier.

Comment: Thank you! I'm testing Parse, it seems very easy for a fast workaround for now. It also provides stats and push notifications services, not that bad...